# Nginx "Permission denied" when creating a folder

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I'm using a simple php script to write / rename files.

By default nginx installation I get "Permission denied" when I run the script.

I tried to changed root html folder permissions from 755 to 777 and it works.

But I think this is not the correct solution for that, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give the files `chown` priviledges, so nginx can access them rather than doing `chmod 777` which means, every system/user can access these files. Try this

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/file
```

don't forget to `sudo service nginx restart` if you are using centos

Comment: So how can I give a file permission when it does not exists yet?

Comment: you can not give a file permission to a file that does not exist

Comment: so there is the problem, I need to create a file on root html folder. In my test, with html permission as 755 I can't create it, but as 777 it works...

Comment: then use my answer replace /file/ with /html/ folder

Comment: thank you for your kindly attention, but it will not be the same than letting 777 permission for html folder?

Comment: DID WORKS! Thank you a lot!

I used the follow, hope is correct: 'sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html'

Before that, on Filezilla the folder and all inside files was displayed as 'root' owner/usergroup, and now it appears as 'nginx', I will have some issue in the future as is?

Comment: Thank you very much @samayo